# Facebook hates my site/like button not loading

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

This is a two part question:

Facebook hates my site.  I tested the like button so many times that now it just shows 'error' in small red writing when I try to like a post on my site.  Other people seem to be able to like my site.

When I try to share my site on my Facebook page, it shows an error there too.

Also, the like button does not even load now, except on individual posts.

I have used the Facebook debugger which except for the app and admin tags, says everything is fine.

Does anyone know how to get a site out of FB's doghouse, and why my like button doesn't load?  Cheers.

My site is http://speechnotrecognised.blogspot.com.au/ and I am using the following FB code including OG tags:

```
xmlns:fb='http://ogp.me/ns/fb#'

<meta expr:content='data:blog.canonicalUrl' property='og:url'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' property='og:description'/>  

<b:if cond='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl'> 
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl' property='og:image'/> 
<b:else/> 
<meta content='http://i1252.photobucket.com/albums/hh569/speechnotrecognised/bc0a9481.jpg' property='og:image'/> 
</b:if> 

<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'> 
<meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName' property='og:title'/> 
<meta content='article' property='og:type'/>
<b:else/> 
<meta expr:content='data:blog.title' property='og:title'/> 
<meta content='blog' property='og:type'/> 
</b:if> 

<div id='fb-root'/>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = &quot;//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&quot;;
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, &#39;script&#39;, &#39;facebook-jssdk&#39;));</script>

<fb:like font='arial' href=' + data:post.canonicalUrl + ' send='false' show_faces='true' width='450'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

That’s what is actually rendered as XFBML tag into the HTML code of your page:

```
<fb:like width="450" show_faces="true" send="false"
  href=" + data:post.canonicalUrl + " font="arial"
  class=" fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget">
```

You can not expect Facebook to know what page on the web `+ data:post.canonicalUrl +` is supposed to be …

So fix your problem with your CMS/template language/whatever you use to create this code, so that it puts an *actual URL* into the href attribute of this element.

Comment: It's blogger code for my country's top level domain.  Facebook should understand it.

Comment: No, Facebook _can not_ understand it, because all it’s scraper sees is `+ data:post.canonicalUrl +` in the place where an HTTP URL is expected. If you were to put `+ data:post.canonicalUrl +` into the address bar of your browser and hit enter – what do you think, where would that get you …? Exactly.